# Groovy Using Single Quote

Tags: groovy

if i have to define a variable listed below i can make use of  ''' to make my things work

```
def MainTable = '''
         0S : MAKE-CALL
         0# : MAKE-CALL
         00 : MAKE-CALL
         (=Emergency) : EMERGENCY-CALL(sip: "911 =domain =dialPhone)
         (=N11) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
         (=SpeedDial) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
         (=PhoneNumber) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialPhone)
         (=ImmediateVSCs) : RETURN
         (=DelayedVSCs) : RETURN
         (x{1-20})S : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)
         (x{1-20})# : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)''';
```

the same variable if i define like this  using single quote it throws me error

```
def MainTable = '
         0S : MAKE-CALL
         0# : MAKE-CALL
         00 : MAKE-CALL
         (=Emergency) : EMERGENCY-CALL(sip: "911 =domain =dialPhone)
         (=N11) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
         (=SpeedDial) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
         (=PhoneNumber) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialPhone)
         (=ImmediateVSCs) : RETURN
         (=DelayedVSCs) : RETURN
         (x{1-20})S : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)
         (x{1-20})# : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)';

1 compilation error:
unexpected char: ''' at line: 1, column: 17
```

how can i use the MainTable  variable using single quote, i don't want to put every thing in a single line

Comment: Why not just use the correct operator? Do you have a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like in Java:

```
def MainTable = '\
     0S : MAKE-CALL\
     0# : MAKE-CALL\
     00 : MAKE-CALL\
     (=Emergency) : EMERGENCY-CALL(sip: "911 =domain =dialPhone)\
     (=N11) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)\
     (=SpeedDial) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)\
     (=PhoneNumber) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialPhone)\
     (=ImmediateVSCs) : RETURN\
     (=DelayedVSCs) : RETURN\
     (x{1-20})S : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)\
     (x{1-20})# : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)';
```

But I fail to see the point in not using tripple single-quotes. If you want to strip the prepended spaces, you can just add .stripIndention() to your string expression:

```
 def myMultilineString = '''
            Some text
            Some more text'''.stripIndent()
```

Comment: groovy> def myMultilineString = ''' 
groovy>             Some text 
groovy>             Some more text'''.stripIndention() 
 
Exception thrown
Apr 10, 2012 1:52:27 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize

WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.stripIndention() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: @anish [`stripIndent()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#stripIndent()) rather than `stripIndentation()` should work

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [the correct answer by sbglasius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084805/6509), I quite like [the `stripMargin()` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#stripMargin()), as you don't need to escape a blank line at the start of your String definition:

```
def mainTable = '''0S : MAKE-CALL
                  |0# : MAKE-CALL
                  |00 : MAKE-CALL
                  |(=Emergency) : EMERGENCY-CALL(sip: "911 =domain =dialPhone)
                  |(=N11) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
                  |(=SpeedDial) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialString)
                  |(=PhoneNumber) : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1v =domain =dialPhone)
                  |(=ImmediateVSCs) : RETURN
                  |(=DelayedVSCs) : RETURN
                  |(x{1-20})S : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)
                  |(x{1-20})# : MAKE-CALL(sip: #1 =domain =dialPhone)'''.stripMargin()
```